# Need to make search and close SVG icons at the same position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make the search icon and the close SVG icon appear at same position but failed to achieve this !

My site: [https://softcroco.com/](https://stackoverflow.com)

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

So, is there any solution to get the search and close SVG icons at same position when the user click on it?

```js
document.getElementById('openSearchButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('searchContainer').style.display = 'flex';
  this.style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('closeButton').style.display = 'block';
});

document.getElementById('closeButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('searchContainer').style.display = 'none';
  this.style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('openSearchButton').style.display = 'block';
});

document.getElementById('searchForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
  const searchQuery = searchInput.value.trim();

  if (searchQuery === '') {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting if the search query is empty
  }
});
```

```css
#submitSearchButton {}

#searchInput {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 15px 145px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 19%important;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-size: 18px;
}

#searchForm {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%!important;
  position: relative;
  display: unset;
}

.search-container {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  /* Change this */
  width: 100%;
  /* Add this */
  top: 0;
  /* Add this */
  left: 0;
  /* Add this */
}

#openSearchButton,
#closeButton {
  padding: 6px!important!;
  border: none!important;
  cursor: pointer!important;
  position: absolute!important;
  background-color: transparent!important;
  color: white!important;
  position: absolute!important;
  /* Change this */
  top: 60%!important;
  transform: translateY(-50%)!important;
  right: 92px!important;
  display: flex!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}

#openSearchButton:hover {
  color: #cccccc!important;
}

#openSearchButton svg {
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out!important;
}

#submitSearchButton {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: -38px;
  right: -97px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

#openSearchButton svg {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

#closeButton svg {
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 1em;
}

#closeButton {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  right: 0;
  /* Add this */
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="search-container" id="searchContainer" style="display: none;">
    <form id="searchForm" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="GET">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search For Apps or Games..." name="s" id="searchInput">
      <button type="submit" id="submitSearchButton">
        <!-- SVG icon code -->
        <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" width="20" height="20"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M208 48c-88.366 0-160 71.634-160 160s71.634 160 160 160 160-71.634 160-160S296.366 48 208 48zM0 208C0 93.125 93.125 0 208 0s208 93.125 208 208c0 48.741-16.765 93.566-44.843 129.024l133.826 134.018c9.366 9.379 9.355 24.575-.025 33.941-9.379 9.366-24.575 9.355-33.941-.025L337.238 370.987C301.747 399.167 256.839 416 208 416 93.125 416 0 322.875 0 208z"></path></svg>
      </button>
    </form>
    <button type="button" id="closeButton">
  <!-- SVG icon code -->
  <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" aria-hidden="true" width="1em" height="1em">
    <path d="M71.029 71.029c9.373-9.372 24.569-9.372 33.942 0L256 222.059l151.029-151.03c9.373-9.372 24.569-9.372 33.942 0 9.372 9.373 9.372 24.569 0 33.942L289.941 256l151.03 151.029c9.372 9.373 9.372 24.569 0 33.942-9.373 9.372-24.569 9.372-33.942 0L256 289.941l-151.029 151.03c-9.373 9.372-24.569 9.372-33.942 0-9.372-9.373-9.372-24.569 0-33.942L222.059 256 71.029 104.971c-9.372-9.373-9.372-24.569 0-33.942z" fill="black"></path>
  </svg>
</button>

  </div>
  <button type="button" id="openSearchButton">
    <!-- Add your search icon SVG code here -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" aria-hidden="true" width="1em" height="1em">
  <path fill="white" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M208 48c-88.366 0-160 71.634-160 160s71.634 160 160 160 160-71.634 160-160S296.366 48 208 48zM0 208C0 93.125 93.125 0 208 0s208 93.125 208 208c0 48.741-16.765 93.566-44.843 129.024l133.826 134.018c9.366 9.379 9.355 24.575-.025 33.941-9.379 9.366-24.575 9.355-33.941-.025L337.238 370.987C301.747 399.167 256.839 416 208 416 93.125 416 0 322.875 0 208z"></path>
</svg>
  </button>
  <!-- Other navigation items -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Your provided link currently links to stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, you assign the same properties to `#openSearchButton` and `#closeButton`, but they are not in the same container and also set to `position: absolute`. Therefore, one of them needs to be adjusted. Since the `#openSearchButton` already appears correctly positioned, we will do it with the `#closeButton`.

I would like to point out that since the snippet does not work, I tried to solve it using the [homepage link](https://softcroco.com/) you provided. The values for the positioning must be adjusted if necessary. Likewise, I also had to use `!important` since it is massively used in the original code.

At the very bottom of your CSS code you already have your own declaration for `#closeButton`. We need to add a `top` and `right` property to override what was previously defined in `#openSearchButton, #closeButton { ... }`. Finally, we also have to assign a `z-index` value, since, as already mentioned, both `#closeButton` and `#openSearchButton` are positioned absolutely and the `#closeButton` is currently below the search bar. So here's the required CSS.

```
#closeButton {
    display: none;
    color: white;
    /* Add this */
    right: 80px !important;
    top: 40% !important;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**EDIT: As pointed out by the OP in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76318907/need-to-make-search-and-close-svg-icons-at-the-same-position#comment134582180_76319222), the solution works 100%, but minor issues still arise. Therefore, further changes have to be made.**

First, in the `#openSearchButton, #closeButton {...}` declaration remove the `transform: translateY(-50%);` as it is superfluous and also the real reason for the last minor problems. But as a result, the positioning must also be readjusted. So here's the required CSS.

```
#openSearchButton, #closeButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    right: 92px;
    padding: 6px;
    border: none;  
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#closeButton {
    display: none;
    top: 17% !important;
    right: 81px !important;
    color: white;        
    z-index: 999;
}
```

I removed `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` from `#openSearchButton, #closeButton {...}` since it has no effect. The display property is added inline by JavaScript (either `block` or `none`).

However, if you want to change this behavior and you want to use `flex` instead of `block` you have to select the element more specifically in the CSS like `.navbar #openSearchButton` and `.navbar #closeButton`. Otherwise, even using `!important` would have no effect in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked 100%, another thing please after applying the changes I have found that open search button not at same position in home page and post pages, what's wrong ?

Comment: Yes, i can confirm that. However, this has nothing to do with home page and post pages I would say, it seems more like this happens after open and close. I will update my answer regarding this.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ferris :) . It worked again. I appreciate your help.